# Can I run minikube without any RBAC?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-apiserver

Can we run minikube without RBAC. Please see the attached screenshot. Looks like RBAC is enabled by default.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in minikube: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2342

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since minikube v0.26.0 the default bootstrapper is kubeadm - which enables RBAC by default.

For the previous versions, you have to explicitly enable it by adding a flag

```
-extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC
```

Otherwise it will not be enabled

To disable RBAC in latest versions of the minikube, set following flag

```
--extra-config=apiserver.authorization-mode=AlwaysAllow
```

If it won't work, try workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2342#issuecomment-479179415)

Comment: is it easy to configure kubeadm to not enable RBAC?

Comment: @user674669 it's just to use old version of kubernetes/minikube without `extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC` flag

Comment: The question was not how to enable RBAC, but how to run minikube without RBAC.

Comment: @lindhe I thought it's straight forward, until you explicitly enable RBAC, it remains  disabled by default.

Comment: But you said that it's enabled by default since v0.26.0 – is that not so?